# Retail Item Class assignment

Tags: python

This program is supposed to take the info for 3 items, store the info then display the info as

> Item 1
>
> Item 2
>
> Item 3

but I'm getting this error: line 47, in main list_display(inventory)
NameError: global name 'list_display' is not defined

I'm new at this and I'm sure I've over looked something but I can't figure it out. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
 # This RetailItem class holds data about products.
class RetailItem:

    # __int__ method initializes the attributes.
    def __init__(self, description, units, price):
        self.__item_description = description
        self.__units_in_inventory = units
        self.__price = price

    # The set_item_description method gets the item type.
    def set_item_description(self, description):
        self.__item_description = description

    # The set_units_in_inventory method gets number of items available.
    def set_units_in_inventory(self, units):
        self.__units_in_inventory = units

    # The set_price method gets the cost of item.
    def set_price(self, price):
        self.__price = price

    # The get_item_description method returns the item type.
    def get_item_description(self):
        return self.__item_description

    # The get_units_in_inventory returns the number of items available.
    def get_units_in_inventory(self):
        return self.__units_in_inventory

    # The get_price method returns the cost of item.
    def get_price(self):
        return self.__price


# This program will test the RetailItem class and return information
# using the mutator method.

import sys

# This defines the main function.
def main():
    # Get a list of RetailItem objects.
    inventory = make_list()

    # Display the data in the list.
    print('Here is the data you entered:')
    list_display(inventory)

    # The make_list will get data for three items. It will
    #return a list of available items.

def make_list():
    # Create an empty list.
    item_list = []

    # Add three item to the list.
    print('Enter data for three items.')
    for count in range(1, 4):
        # Get item data.
        print('Item number ' + str(count) + ':')
        item = input('Enter description of item: ')
        units = float(input('Enter number of units in inventory: '))
        price = float(input('Enter price per item: '))
        print()

        # Creat new RetailItem and assign items variable.
        items = RetailItem(item, units, price)
        # Add items to list.
        item_list.append(items)

        return item_list
    
    #Display the items information.
    def display_list(item_list):
        for item in item_list:
            print(item.get_item_description())
            print(item.get_units_in_inventory())
            print(item.get_price())
            print()
            
# Call the main function.
main()
```

Comment: That's because `list_display` is not defined. You do however have a method called `display_list` if that's what you wanted to type instead.

Comment: Also make sure to un-indent it if the above is the case. And just so you know, it will only ever work for one item because you have the line `return item_list` inside of your for loop. Thus it will only work for one item. Unless that is also an indentation error.

Comment: Also getters and setters are utterly unnecessary in Python - access the attributes directly (as none of your setters and getters actually *do anything*) or use a `@property`.

Comment: don't use `__foo` for attribute names; it doesn't do anything useful and mostly causes pain.  and yes, you very very rarely want getters and setters like this in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is that you are calling the wrong function, `list_display(inventory)`, and you have defined `display_list(item_list)` inside `make_list()`. 
I have moved `display_list(item_list)` out of `make_list()` and change `list_display(inventory)` to `display_list(inventory)`.

```
 # This RetailItem class holds data about products.
class RetailItem:

    # __int__ method initializes the attributes.
    def __init__(self, description, units, price):
        self.__item_description = description
        self.__units_in_inventory = units
        self.__price = price

    # The set_item_description method gets the item type.
    def set_item_description(self, description):
        self.__item_description = description

    # The set_units_in_inventory method gets number of items available.
    def set_units_in_inventory(self, units):
        self.__units_in_inventory = units

    # The set_price method gets the cost of item.
    def set_price(self, price):
        self.__price = price

    # The get_item_description method returns the item type.
    def get_item_description(self):
        return self.__item_description

    # The get_units_in_inventory returns the number of items available.
    def get_units_in_inventory(self):
        return self.__units_in_inventory

    # The get_price method returns the cost of item.
    def get_price(self):
        return self.__price


# This program will test the RetailItem class and return information
# using the mutator method.

import sys

# This defines the main function.
def main():
    # Get a list of RetailItem objects.
    inventory = make_list()

    # Display the data in the list.
    print('Here is the data you entered:')
    display_list(inventory)

    # The make_list will get data for three items. It will
    #return a list of available items.

def make_list():
    # Create an empty list.
    item_list = []

    # Add three item to the list.
    print('Enter data for three items.')
    for count in range(1, 4):
        # Get item data.
        print('Item number ' + str(count) + ':')
        item = input('Enter description of item: ')
        units = float(input('Enter number of units in inventory: '))
        price = float(input('Enter price per item: '))
        print()

        # Creat new RetailItem and assign items variable.
        items = RetailItem(item, units, price)
        # Add items to list.
        item_list.append(items)

        return item_list

#Display the items information.
def display_list(item_list):
    for item in item_list:
        print(item.get_item_description())
        print(item.get_units_in_inventory())
        print(item.get_price())
        print()

# Call the main function.
main()
```